# page number does not appear on first page of bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, page-numbering

When I make my bibliography, something strange happens. If the bibliography is more than one page, the page number is not included on the first page. I want the page number on bottom-center of the first page, just like it is in the following pages. If I take out a few of the citations in chapter one so that the bibliography fits on one page, the first page of the bibliography has a page number. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{thesis}

\usepackage[lmargin=1.5in, rmargin=1.0in, tmargin=2.0in, bmargin=1.25in, footskip=0.35in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{fancy}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont \centering}{CHAPTER \chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{11 pt}{}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\cite{ClusteringBook}
\cite{HSOM}
\cite{ImageSegClustering}
\cite{Conscience}
\cite{Iris}
\cite{Kohonen}
\cite{LabelSOM}
\cite{kMeans1}
\cite{GrowingGrid}
\cite{UstarClustering}
\cite{GA_SOM}


\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{references}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\clearpage


\end{document}
```

I don't know how to add the `references.bib` file so I'll just paste it in here - I apologize for this as I'm sure there is a better way of doing this. Feel free to tell me a better way of including my references (maybe a dummy reference file) and I can change this.

```
@book{Kohonen,
 editor = {Teuvo Kohonen and Manfred Schroeder and Thomas Huang},
 title = {Self-{O}rganizing {M}aps},
 year = {2001},
 isbn = {3540679219},
 edition = {3rd},
 publisher = {Springer-Verlag New York, Inc.},
 address = {Secaucus, NJ, USA},
} 

@book{ClusteringBook,
  author = {Gan, Guojun and Ma, Chaoqun and Wu, Jianhong},
  howpublished = {Paperback},
  isbn = {0898716233},
  posted-at = {2010-05-21 23:59:45},
  priority = {2},
  publisher = {SIAM, Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics},
  title = {{Data {C}lustering: {T}heory, {A}lgorithms, and {A}pplications ({ASA-SIAM} {S}eries on {S}tatistics and {A}pplied {P}robability)}},
  year = {2007}
}

% Data

@Article{Iris,
  author =  "R. A. Fisher",
  title = {{T}he {U}se of {M}ultiple {M}easurements in {T}axonomic {P}roblems},
  journal = "Annals of Eugenics",
  year =    "1936",
  volume =  "7",
  pages =   "179--188"
}

@TechReport{Wine,
  author = {S. Aeberhard and D. Coomans and O. de Vel},
  title = {{C}omparison of {C}lassifiers in {H}igh {D}imensional {S}ettings},
  year = {1992}, 
  institution =  {Dept. of Computer Science and Dept. of Mathematics and Statistics, James Cook University of North Queensland},
  number = {92-2}
}

@InProceedings{Glass,
  author =  "I. W. Evett and E. J. Spiehler",
  title =   "{R}ule {I}nduction in {F}orensic {S}cience",
  booktitle =   "KBS in Goverment",
  year =    "1987",
  pages =   "107--118",
  publisher_address = "Pinner, UK",
  publisher = "Online Publications"
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{ControlChart,
    author = {R. J. Alcock and Y. Manolopoulos},
    title = {{T}ime-series {S}imilarity {Q}ueries {E}mploying a {F}eature-{B}ased {A}pproach},
    booktitle = {In 7 th Hellenic Conference on Informatics, Ioannina},
    year = {1999},
    pages = {27--29}
}

@article{ColonCancer,
    address = {Department of Molecular Biology, Princeton University, Princeton, NJ 08540, USA.},
    author = {U. Alon, and N. Barkai and D. A. Notterman and K. Gish and S. Ybarra and D. Mack and A. J. Levine},
    day = {8},
    doi = {10.1073/pnas.96.12.6745},
    issn = {0027-8424},
    journal = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America},
    month = jun,
    number = {12},
    pages = {6745--6750},
    pmid = {10359783},
    posted-at = {2010-07-02 02:37:07},
    priority = {0},
    title = {{B}road patterns of gene expression revealed by clustering analysis of tumor and normal colon tissues probed by oligonucleotide arrays},
    volume = {96},
    year = {1999}
}

% Software

@misc{SOMtoolbox,
      author = {Esa Alhoniemi and Johan Himberg and Juha Parhankangas and Juha Vesanto},
      title = "{SOM} {T}oolbox",
      year = 2005,
      url = "http://www.cis.hut.fi/projects/somtoolbox",
      note = "Accessed: 5/02/2011"
}

@book{MATLAB:2010,
  year = {2010},
  author = {MATLAB},
  title = {version 7.10.0 (R2010a)},
  publisher = {The MathWorks Inc.},
  address = {Natick, Massachusetts}
}

@misc{jfree,
    author = {Gilbert, David and Morgner, Thomas},
    citeulike-article-id = {1104142},
    keywords = {bibtex-import},
    posted-at = {2007-02-13 04:22:04},
    priority = {0},
    title = {{JFreeChart}},
    year = {2003 - 2005}
}


% Quality Measures

@InCollection{TEfirstsecondBMU,
  author =  "K. Kiviluoto",
  title =   "{T}opology {P}reservation in {S}elf-{O}rganizing {M}aps",
  booktitle =   "International Conference on Neural Networks",
  pages =   "294--299",
  year =    "1996",
  publisher =   "IEEE Press",
}

@Article{TEtopProd,
  author =  "Hans-Ulrich Bauer and Klaus R. Pawelzik",
  title =   "{Q}uantifying the {N}eighborhood {P}reservation of
         {S}elf-{O}rganizing {F}eature {M}aps",
  type =    "Paper",
  journal = "IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks",
  year =    "1992",
  volume =  "3",
  number =  "4",
  pages =   "570--579",
  month =   jul,
}

% Learning Rate & Paramters

@Article{PLSOM,
  title = "{I}mproved {PLSOM} {A}lgorithm",
  author = "Erik Berglund",
  journal = "Appl. Intell",
  year = "2010",
  number = "1",
  volume = "32",
  pages = "122--130",
}

@InProceedings{Conscience,
  author = "D. DeSieno",
  title = "{A}dding a {C}onscience to {C}ompetitive {L}earning",
  pages = "117--124",
  booktitle = "IEEE International Conference on Neural Networks",
  volume = "1",
  organization = "(San Diego 1988)",
  publisher = "IEEE",
  address = "New York",
  year = "1988",
}


% Clustering/Classification

@Article{SOMclustering,
    author = {Juha Vesanto and Esa Alhoniemi},
    title = {{C}lustering of the {S}elf-{O}rganizing {M}ap}, 
    journal = {IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks}, 
    publisher = {IEEE},
    year = {2000},
    volume = {11},
    number = {3},
    month = {May},
    pages = {586--600},
    note = {},
    annote = {}
}

@InProceedings{ImageSegClustering,  
  author = {D. Opolon and F. Moutarde},
  booktitle = {In Proc. of ESANN'2004, Bruges},
  pages = {507-512},
  title = {{F}ast semi-automatic segmentation algorithm for {S}elf-{O}rganizing {M}aps},
  year = {2004},
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{LabelSOM,
    author = {Andreas Rauber},
    title = {{L}abel{SOM}: {O}n the {L}abeling of {S}elf-{O}rganizing {M}aps},
    booktitle = {In Proc. International Joint Conference on Neural Networks},
    year = {1999},
    pages = {1--6}
}

@InProceedings{Pmatrix,
  author = "A. Ultsch",
  booktitle = "In Proceedings Workshop on Self-Organizing Maps (WSOM 2003)",
  pages = "225--230",
  title = "{M}aps for the {V}isualization of high-dimensional {D}ata {S}paces",
  address = "Kyushu, Japan",  
  year = 2003
}

@techreport{UstarMatrix,  
  author = {Ultsch, Alfred},
  title = {U*-{M}atrix: a {T}ool to visualize {C}lusters in high dimensional {D}ata},
  school = {CS Department, Philipps-University Marburg, Germany},
  address = {Marburg, Germany},  
  number = {36},
  year = 2004
}

@InProceedings{UstarClustering,
  author = "Alfred Ultsch and Fabian. Moutarde",
  booktitle = "Workshop on Self-Organizing Maps (WSOM'2005), Paris",
  pages = " 25-32",
  title = "{U}*{F} {CLUSTERING: A NEW PERFORMANT CLUSTER-MINING METHOD BASED ON SEGMENTATION OF SELF-ORGANIZING MAPS}",
  address = "Paris, France",
  year = 2005
}

@InProceedings{LabelProp,
  author = {Alfred Ultsch and Lutz Herrmann},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 6th International Workshop on Self-Organizing Maps (WSOM 2007)},
  title = {Label {P}ropagation for {S}emi-{S}upervised {L}earning in {S}elf-{O}rganizing {M}aps},
  publisher = {Neuroinformatics Group Bienfeld University, Germany},
  address = {Germany},
  year = 2007
}


% Fast BMU searches

@TechReport{FastBMUsearch1,
author = {T. Kohonen},
title = {Report {A}33},
institution = {Laboratory of Computer and Information Sciene, Helsinki University of Technology},
year = {1996},
OPTaddress = {Espoo, Finland},
}


@InProceedings{FastBMUsearch2,
  author =       {Makoto KINOUCHI and KUDO Yoshihiro},
  title =        {{M}uch faster learning algorithm for {B}atch-{L}earning {SOM} and its application to {B}ioinformatics},
  booktitle =    {Proceedings of the Workshop on Self-Organizing Maps ({WSOM}'03)},
  pages =        {},
  year =         {2003},
  address =      {Kitakyushu, Japan},
  month =        {September},
}

% Supervised Methods

@ARTICLE{Phonetic,
AUTHOR = "Teuvo Kohonen",
TITLE = "{T}he {N}eural {P}honetic {T}ypewriter",
JOURNAL = "IEEE Computer",
PAGES = {11-22},
YEAR = {1988},
}

@inproceedings{Phonotopic,
    address = {Silver Spring, MD},
    author = {Kohonen, Teuvo and M{\"a}kisara, Kai and Saram{\"a}ki, Tapio},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 6th International Conference on Pattern Recognition},
    pages = {182--185},
    posted-at = {2008-03-11 13:01:28},
    priority = {2},
    publisher = {{IEEE} Computer Society Press},
    title = {Phonotopic Maps---{I}nsightful {R}epresentation of {P}honological {F}eatures for {S}peech {R}ecognition},
    year = {1984}
}

@inproceedings{kMeans1,
 author = {Ba\c{c}\~{a}o, Fernando and Lobo, Victor and Painho, Marco},
 title = {Self-organizing maps as substitutes for k-means clustering},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 5th international conference on Computational Science - Volume Part III},
 series = {ICCS'05},
 year = {2005},
 pages = {476--483},
 publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
 address = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
} 

% GAs

@inproceedings{GA_SOM,
 author = {Cateni, Silvia and Colla, Valentina and Vannucci, Marco},
 title = {A {G}enetic {A}lgorithms-based {A}pproach for {S}electing the {M}ost {R}elevant {I}nput {V}ariables in {C}lassification {T}asks},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2010 Fourth UKSim European Symposium on Computer Modeling and Simulation},
 series = {EMS '10},
 year = {2010},
 isbn = {978-0-7695-4308-6},
 pages = {63--67},
 numpages = {5},
 url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/EMS.2010.23},
 doi = {10.1109/EMS.2010.23},
 acmid = {1932715},
 publisher = {IEEE Computer Society},
 address = {Washington, DC, USA},
 keywords = {variable selection, calssification, genetic algorithms, self organizing maps},
 }

@ARTICLE{HSOM,
    author = {Risto Miikkulainen},
    title = {{S}cript {R}ecognition with {H}ierarchical {F}eature {M}aps},
    journal = {Connection Science},
    year = {1990},
    volume = {2},
    pages = {83--101}
}

@ARTICLE{GrowingGrid,
    author = {Bernd Fritzke},
     title = {{G}rowing {G}rid - a {S}elf-{O}rganizing {N}etwork with constant neighborhood range and adaptation strength},
     journal = {Neural Processing Letters},
     year = {1995},
     volume = {2},
     pages = {9--13}
 }
```

Comment: There are quite a few document classes called `thesis`. Do you know the provenance of yours? This will likely be important for figuring out what may be going on. If I compile your MWE with either the `report` or the `book` document class, I cannot generate the missing page number issue you're describing. Incidentally, I had to fix a couple of typos in the bib portion of your MWE -- a missing comma between fields, and invalid field delimiters in one case -- that prevented BibTeX from being able to do its job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `etoolbox` package to modify the  behaviour of the first `\bibitem` and to issue the instruction `\thispagestyle`.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{firstbib}
\booltrue{firstbib}
\preto{\bibitem}{\ifbool{firstbib}{\thispagestyle{fancy}\setbool{firstbib}{false}}{}}
```

Comment: It seems a shot in the dark; or did the crystal ball work? +1 anyway.

Comment: A complete (educated) shot in the dark, based on the (reasonably safe) assumptions that the `(the)bibliography` environment is defined as list, and the it uses `\bibitem` (and that there at least one `\bibitem`)