# remove page number in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, page-numbering

I do not want page number to be displayed in my bibliography. So I tried gobble like this:

```
\bibliography{MyLibrary}{}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
```

It is fine as long as my bibliography is 1 page long. But now my references spread to two pages, only the second page doesn't show page number. The first page (that has the Bibliography heading) still shows page number. How do I remove page number on both pages?
My preamble is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge
```

}

Comment: just use fancyhdr and create a custom pagestyle, or use the empty pagestyle, for the bibliography.

Comment: I already tried the empty pagestyle without luck. It seems that the bibliography overwrites it somewhere

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me. Add the line before your bibliography starts:

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{}
```

Comment: +1. It does remove page number on both pages of my bibliography, but it also remove page number of one page right before the bibliography (my conclusion page). Any idea?

Comment: @TuBui In my document, I have the commands in this order:
`\FloatBarrier % \clearpage % \renewcommand{\thepage}{} % \bibliographystyle{plainnat} % \bibliography{library} %`

Comment: Use \break before the posted command to ensure you retain the last page number

Answer (score 2):

Just managed to work around with it thanks to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73798/page-number-does-not-appear-on-first-page-of-bibliography?rq=1). It used `preto` command in the `etoolbox` package to set the pagestyle of the first page in the bibliography.
Add the etoolbox package to my header:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
```

Then add the 3 commands before the bibliography:

```
\newbool{firstbib}
\booltrue{firstbib}
\preto{\bibitem}{\ifbool{firstbib}{\thispagestyle{empty}\setbool{firstbib}{false}}{}}
\bibliography{MyLibrary}{}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
```

It works for now. But I still like to hear about the true solution for this

Comment: with this approach I got first and last pages without numbers. Is there a way to get only the first without number? Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

To ensure, that the page before the bibliography still has the page number use `\newpage` before `\renewcommand{\thepage}{}`

```
\chapter{xxx}
\newpage
\renewcommand{\thepage}{}
\bibliography{bib/xxx}
```

Comment: Does this really work?