# remove first page numbering in bibliography (bibtex)

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, numbering

How is it possible to remove the page number only on the first page of bibliography. I have these lines to generate the bibliography list:

```
\bibliographystyle{abnt}
\bibliography{references}
```

I got close to what I want using [\usepackage{etoolbox}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153254/remove-page-number-in-bibliography?rq=1) but instead of only the first I got also the last page without header number.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

The answers is almost ready in a previous [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153254/remove-page-number-in-bibliography?rq=1), I've just made some minor changes.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
...
\begin{document}

\newbool{firstbib}
\booltrue{firstbib}
\preto{\bibitem}\ifbool{firstbib}\thispagestyle{empty}\setbool{firstbib}{false}}{}}
\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{style}
```