# Remove word 'pages' in bibliography fields

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to remove the word "***pages***" in formatted bibliographic entries. I am using `natbib` with the bibliography style `unsrtnat`. I have the following MWE:

[image]

If we look at source 2, it has the word *pages*, which I would like to remove to be consistent with source 1.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[english,twoside,12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[numbers, sort&compress]{natbib} % Nice references.
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}            
\begin{document}
We cite \citet{erhan2006collaborative} \citet{exarchos2006protein}.
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

and the `references.bib` file contains:

```
@article{erhan2006collaborative,
    title={Collaborative filtering on a family of biological targets},
    author={Erhan, Dumitru and L'Heureux, Pierre-Jean and Yue, Shi Yi and Bengio, Yoshua},
    journal={Journal of Chemical Information and Modeling},
    volume={46},
    number={2},
    pages={626--635},
    year={2006},
    publisher={ACS Publications}
}

@inproceedings{exarchos2006protein,
    title={Protein classification using sequential pattern mining},
    author={Exarchos, Themis P. and Papaloukas, Costas and Lampros, Christos and Fotiadis, Dimitrios I.},
    booktitle={Engineering in Medicine and Biology Society, 2006. EMBS'06. 28th Annual International Conference of the IEEE},
    pages={5814--5817},
    year={2006},
    organization={IEEE}
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend making such a modification to (a copy of) the file `unsrtnat.bst`: In entries of type `@inproceedings`, numbers (and ranges of numbers) can appear in quite a few places. If one omits the prefix "pages" (or "page" for a single-page entry), your readers may not be able to figure out which numbers represent pages and which numbers represent something else.

Comment: Normally I would keep it, but a colleague of mine had their professor complain out inconsistent formatting, and they gave me this problem, and now it has piqued my interest about how I would do it if I needed to. Perhaps an alternative would be to abbreviate it to ***pg.***

Comment: see this post -- it may be helpful https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153254/remove-page-number-in-bibliography

Comment: @Tina , that is a similar sounding but unrelated question.

Comment: Did anyone find the answer? This seems to be a common task for research paper formatting in Latex.

Comment: @AnshKhurana, not that I know of yet.