# First page of bibliography doesn't display page number

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I need to do my thesis and I have used a template of my university in Overleaf.
But I have one problem: My first page of the bibliography doesn't display the page number, like in this figure:

[image: problem number page]

And you can see that the other pages display page number:

[image: normal page number after first page]

How can I fix it?

Comment: try this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73804/121944

Comment: or try this: `\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}` before you print the bibliography.

Comment: using "\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}" I have LaTeX Error: \bibsetup undefined.

Comment: try this: tex.stackexchange.com/a/73804/121944 – AML 19 mins ago -> I didn't use bibitem, I use bibtex from google scholar, because of that, the solution of the page doesn't work for me. Tnks

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: @book{brummer2006rheology,
  title={Rheology essentials of cosmetic and food emulsions},
  author={{Brummer, Rudiger}},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\bibpreamble}{\thispagestyle{myheadings}}` instead.

Comment: This work for me !! Thanks a Lot, LianTze Lim !! :)

Comment: @LianTzeLim Do you want to add an answer?

Comment: ah, didn't get notified that the OP got that to work. adding.

Comment: @Jesse You are overwriting \bibsetup, doing so you lose all valuable lines such as penalty-related instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You can get `\bibpreamble` to do this for you:

```
\renewcommand{\bibpreamble}{\thispagestyle{myheadings}}
```

`\bibsetup`, as suggested in the comments, is only available if you use `biblatex`. I was going on a hunch that you're using the `natbib` package instead, which inserts `\bibpreamble` just before the reference list, after the Reference/Bibliography heading.

If you were not using `natbib` either, you may have had to use e.g. `etoolbox` to patch the `thebibliography` environment instead:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\chapter*{\bibname}}
  {\chapter*{\bibname}\thispagestyle{headings}}
  {}{}
```

though the exact patch would depend on the `.cls` you're using. I'm assuming the same `thebibliography` from `book.cls` here.

Answer (score 1):

For `biblatex` :
do **NOT** use

```
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{headings}}
```

as it will **overwrite valuable setup lines**.

Instead, patch the command if you can, or restore the whole original definition along with your additional instruction:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{
 \interlinepenalty=5000\relax
  \widowpenalty=10000\relax
  \clubpenalty=10000\relax
  \raggedbottom
  \frenchspacing
  \biburlsetup
  \thispagestyle{headings}}
```